# Bounding the absolute sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have a basic question in probability that is useful in my research.

Let $X_1, X_1'$ be i.i.d. random variables, and $X_2,X_2'$ be i.i.d. random variables, although the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ may be different. Further, suppose that $X_1,X_1',X_2,X_2'$ are independent. Then, is the following true?
$$\mathbb{E}|X_1+X_1'| + \mathbb{E}|X_2+X_2'| \geq 2 \mathbb{E}|X_1 + X_2|?$$

If so, then how to prove this? And otherwise, what is a counterexample?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: By the way, you may assume that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have mean $0$, if that helps anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Take $X_2$ to be 100 times Rademacher(1/2), and $X_1$ to be 0.0001 times a Rademacher (1/2). The left side will be around 100, and the right side will be around 200.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry. Your example is correct! Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to apologize for asking a question; good luck with your research!